# Given the cumulative distribution find the probability density

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Given the cumulative distribution $F(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ if $x\ge 0$, otherwise $F(x)=0$.

I calculated the probability density by doing the derivative of $\frac{x}{x+1}$ which is $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ but I don't know if the probability density is $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$  when $x\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise, or it's $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ when $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise. My textbook says it's $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$  when $x\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise but I don't understand why.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you choose. Note that, for a given cumulative distribution function (CDF), the according probability density function (PDF) is not unique.

A PDF is any measurable function $f$ that satisfies (where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure)
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(\tau)\, \lambda(\mathrm d\tau) \quad \text{for all } x\in\Bbb R.$$

Comment: Clearly, both functions that you mentioned satisfy this property in your case; so they are both PDFs for your CDF.

More generally: If two functions $g,h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ coincide $\lambda$-almost everywhere, i.e. there exist a $\lambda$-null set $\mathcal N$ and a $\Omega\subset\mathcal N$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x=\Omega$, then 
$$\int_A f\,\mathrm d\lambda=\int_A g\,\mathrm d\lambda \quad \text{for all measurable } A\subset\Bbb R.$$